# Routing OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, openvpn-connect

I'm using OpenVPN on a Macbook as client and OpenVPN on Linux as server at work. My network at work is 192.168.x.x.

When I share my smartphone internet connection with my Macbook, the VPN works fine and I can connect the server at work.

But when I'm trying from home it's not working, I can't connect servers at work.

I think the issue comes from the network at home is also 192.168.x.x. When I go on 192.168.1.1 from home with VPN connected, I've the home router page and not the touter page from work.

Internet connection works fine. OpenVPN Client give the address 10.8.x.x

What do you think ? How can I solve it ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Enjoy your day

Ghislain

Answer (score 0):

As of now 28-4-2022,
I faced similar issue with openvpn, well I realized my setup was wrong, I was using same connector or .ovpn profile for both client and server.
Later I created a new user as a client, which provided me a separate client and it worked